# Is this the correct sample space and event?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Toss a (fair) coin twice and find the probability that heads occurs EXACTLY once.

**Sample Space $S$**: $S = \{ H, H, T, T\}$ and $A = \{H, T\}$

Thus $1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2$.

But is this correct? **The book points out that**

$S = \{HT, TH, HH, TT \}$ is the correct sample space. **Explain?**

Comment: The problem with your soultion is that it accounts only for the outcome of 1 experiment twice. You need to considrt the outcome of both (once, of course)

Answer (score 1):

Either you toss a coin twice or tossing two coins is same thing.

**Case 1-**

Both Heads - HH

**Case 2-**

One Head and One Tail or One Tail and One Head - HT, TH

**Case 3-**

Both Tails - TT

**Sample space** = {HH, HT, TH, TT}

Favourable cases = {HT, TH}

Probability = $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$